# 3Ware 9500s Raid array not visible in Windows 7 x64 disk management - latest firmware and drivers

Tags: windows-7, raid5, 3ware

I bought a used 3Ware 9500s-4LP raid controller from Ebay (the old 3ware 8506-4lp didn't support RAID arrays over 2TB, but it was working), installed it in my server and attached it to the SATA backplane with my 3 2TB WD Red drives.

I configured the RAID via the RAID bios (ALT+3 on boot) as RAID 0/1 and 5 - I tried them all.

Back in Windows, I installed the drivers and 3DM2 (latest from http://www.lsi.com/support/Pages/download-results.aspx?productcode=P00258&assettype=0&component=Storage%20Component&productfamily=Legacy%20RAID%20Controllers&productname=3ware%209500S%20series)

As i looked for the RAID drive in Disk Management, there was only the system HDD visible.

How can that be?

I tried everything on Windows Server 2008 R2 also, no change.

The server I am working with is a Maxdata Platinum Server 520 with an Intel SE7320EP2 Motherboard. Latest BIOS installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, the lastest drivers (9.5.4) made problems - tried 9.5.3 which the support sent to me - they worked.

Still have to try 3DM2 if it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of experience with 3ware 9600 series cards (predominantly the 8 and 16 port variants) and LSI/3ware recommend that both the drivers AND the cards firmware are updated.  Don't know if this relates to your issue.

Also important to note that if a card is already installed and running then the driver would need to be updated before the firmware as otherwise you can break your array.